# How to display validation error near textbox

Tags: php

I have this form in index.php

```
<form action="result.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="word" class="tbox">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Generate Now">
</form>
```

In result.php i am checking whether the input matches all validation condition and generating the output. Now, if it doesnt match, i ve to throw an error near my text box. Is that possible through php?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using PHP, you may try like below

```
<input type="text" name="word" class="tbox"> <?php if(isset($_POST['word']) && $_POST['word'] == ''){ echo 'YOUR ERROR MESSAGE'; } ?>
```

Comment: But the page is redirecting . So i am unable to see the message. Do i ve to use die()?

Comment: remove result.php from `<form>` tage and leave it like this `<form action="" method="post">`

Comment: <form action="result.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="word" class="tbox">
    <?php
     if(isset($_POST['word']) && $_POST['word'] == '')
     {
     $error = ""
     }
     ?>

Comment: but i ve to pass this variable word to result.php

Answer (score 2):

a few things, one you can just post against the page itself not great to have DB functions and the like in user reachable areas so check out includes and use them to reference the single page.

Then make a simple variable and slide it into your form as such

```
<? echo $error ?>
```

and set error to something via the php script imported from result.php, or you may want to learn about sessions and get variables if combining the files via include isn't on the table.

Once its working then say make a div box as such

```
<? if (isset($error)){?><div class="errorbox"><? echo $error?></div><? }?>
```

Comment: since the page is redirecting, i am unable to see the error message. do i need to use die()?

Comment: die() no just don't bother with the redirect and declare it first

basically include up top reads post variables
page on bottom changes as a result of post variables